# az cli missing on docker image on mac after doing curl call

Tags: azure, docker, azure-cli

I have the following in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get install vim -y
COPY . /builds
RUN curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash
RUN apt-get install curl && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install nodejs
RUN npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true
```

At this point if I create a container using this new image, on my windows host I can do this:

```
root@5a75ab66011b:/builds# az --version
azure-cli                         2.35.0

core                              2.35.0
telemetry                          1.0.6

Dependencies:
msal                              1.17.0
azure-mgmt-resource               20.0.0

Python location '/opt/az/bin/python3'
Extensions directory '/root/.azure/cliextensions'

Python (Linux) 3.8.12 (default, Apr  1 2022, 06:20:19)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal


Your CLI is up-to-date.

Please let us know how we are doing: https://aka.ms/azureclihats
and let us know if you're interested in trying out our newest features: https://aka.ms/CLIUXstudy
root@5a75ab66011b:/builds#
```

On my m1 macbook pro:

```
root@4fb97a21813a:/builds# az
qemu-x86_64: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory
root@4fb97a21813a:/builds#
```

So I tried to manually redo the curl command like this:

```
root@4fb97a21813a:/builds# curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease                                                                                            
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease                                                                             
Hit:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli bullseye InRelease                                                                                  
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x bullseye InRelease             
Reading package lists... Done                       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
apt-transport-https is already the newest version (2.2.4).
curl is already the newest version (7.74.0-1.3+deb11u1).
gnupg is already the newest version (2.2.27-2+deb11u1).
lsb-release is already the newest version (11.1.0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease                                                                      
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease                                                       
Hit:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli bullseye InRelease                                                            
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x bullseye InRelease             
Reading package lists... Done                       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
azure-cli is already the newest version (2.35.0-1~bullseye).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

root@4fb97a21813a:/builds# az
qemu-x86_64: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory
root@4fb97a21813a:/builds#
```

It seems to be indicating that I have installed azure-cli ... but it won't run.
Any tips would be appreciated.

**Edit 1**

I've tried building the image like this:

```
docker build -t azuredeployment . --platform linux/amd64
```

instead of:

```
docker build -t azuredeployment .
```

but no dice.  I get the same results.

I also tried to change the way I run the docker container but I can't seem to get the command going :

```
 docker run -d azuredeployment --platform linux/x86_64
```

gives me the error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "--platform": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

**EDIT 2**

Got it mostly working.
I changed the docker file from this:

```
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 \
```

to this:

```
 FROM --platform=linux/amd64 mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
```

and it works.  Albeit, I have this little icon with an exclamation mark next to it in docker desktop saying the image may not run properly.

I also tried to use the arm64 version like this:

```
 FROM --platform=linux/arm64 mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
```

I don't have the warning icon next to my running container but ... i still get the same error message.

**EDIT 3**

So in this end, this is the syntax I'm working with in the FROM :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.202-bullseye-slim-amd64
RUN apt update && apt-get install vim -y
COPY . /builds
RUN curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash
RUN apt-get install curl && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install nodejs
RUN npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true
```

It seems the az cli installs properly.  But here's a screenshot showing the status of the running container.  You can also see the warning icon I was trying to describe.

[image]

Comment: Could you please let us know ,what is the status of your container is showing..?

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT please see edit 3